# Knockout reduce if/else repetition

Tags: knockout.js

I have a bunch of repetitive if/else statement that I want to simply.
The purpose of the statement is to render the correct element and bindings for an item.

The most repetitive part of the code is the autocomplete.

```
<div>
    <!-- ko if: type === 'text' -->
        <!-- ko if: hasAutocomplete() -->
            <input data-bind="textInput: val, autocomplete: { data: choices, other_parameters... }" />
        <!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko ifnot: hasAutocomplete() -->
            <input data-bind="textInput: val" />
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko if: type === 'date' -->
        <!-- ko if: hasAutocomplete -->    
            <input data-bind="dateInput: val, autocomplete: { data: choices, other_parameters... }" />
        <!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko ifnot: hasAutocomplete -->    
            <input data-bind="dateInput: val" />    
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->

    etc...

</div>
```

**Update solution**

The solution that I am thinking is to

1.Create a binding that will add the `autocomplete` binding by calling `applyBindingsToNode` if `hasAutocomplete` is true:

```
<input data-bind="dateInput: val, optionalautocomplete" />
```

2.Use templates instead of if binding (thanks U10!)

**Is that the right solution? Any other suggestions?**

Comment: How about a switch statement?

Answer (score 2):

One of possible solutions that I see is to use templates:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: type() + hasAutocomplete() ? '-autocomplere': '', data: buyer }"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="text">
     <input data-bind="textInput: val" />
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="text-autocomplete">
     <input data-bind="textInput: val, autocomplete: { data: choices }" />
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="date">
     <input data-bind="dateInput: val" />
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="date-autocomplete">
     <input data-bind="dateInput: val, autocomplete: { data: choices }" />
</script>
```

Or move template choosing to computed like:

```
this.templateName= ko.computed(function() {
    return type() + hasAutocomplete() ? '-autocomplere': '';
}, this);
```

Another possible solution is to create [custom element](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-custom-elements.html).

Comment: It certainly looks nicer but the markup is still repetitive for my taste. There are two types of date and text. Thanks!

Comment: @LostInComputer, that you definitely need to create a binding-wrapper which will choose needed bindings and add then inside itself.

Comment: @LostInComputer, but in that case it will looks less extendable.

Comment: @LostInComputer, there is another way - create custom element.http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-custom-elements.html

Comment: How will components help?

Comment: How many of these input elements do you have on your page? (The "dynamically named templates" approach is actually a pretty good one. If that doesn't reduce duplication for you then you don't actually have that much duplication on your page to begin with.)